# Distributed cache for key-value pairs

Tags: java, caching, redis, distributed-caching

I'm looking for a distributed cache for key-value pairs with these features -

1. Persistence to disk
2. Open Source
3. Java Interface
4. Fast read/write with minimum memory utilisation
5. Easy to add more machines to the database (Horizontally Scalable)

What are the databases that fit the bill?

Comment: Anything you looked for? Give your inputs as well.

Comment: I looked redis and memcached. But I don't have much idea about this. I'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of options that you can make use of.

Redis - the one you've stated by yourself. Its a distinct process, very fast, key-value for sure, but it's not an "in-memory with your application", I mean that you'll always do a socket I/O in order to go to redis process. 
Its not written in Java, but it provides a descent Java Driver to work with, moreover there is a spring integration.

If you want a java based solution consider the following:

[memcached](http://memcached.org/)  - a distributed cache

[Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) - its a datagrid, its much more than simply key-value store, but you might be interested in this as well.

[Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/) - folks from JBoss have created this one

[EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) - a popular distributed cache

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I have zero idea of distributed caches. So, if I have around 100M records, which would the best option with most of the features?

Comment: a simple get will probably work with all of them. I think you should be also concerned about other aspects like speed, deployment, licensing and so forth. You can do your benchmarks in your environment. In general there are a lot of head-to-head comparisons available in the internet. Example: http://vschart.com/compare/hazelcast/vs/redis-database

Answer (score 1):

[Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework also provides distributed cache abilities based on Redis